# reuse redux reducers and actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Lets say I have a section reducer to hold the section's data

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  section: ''
};

const sectionReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign(
        {},
        state,
        {
          section: action.section,
          data: action.data
        }
      );
  }
  return state;
}
```

And I need couple sections with the same data structure and actions. Then how can I do it like this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import sectionReducer from './sectionReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  sectionA: sectionReducer,
  sectionB: sectionReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

The action is as simple as

```
import sectionAData from '../data/sectionAData';
...
export const importDataSuccess = (section, data) => {
  return {
    type: types.IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS,
    section: section,
    data
  }
}

export const loadData = (section) => {
  const dataSet = (() => {
    switch(section) {
      case "SECTIONA":
        return sectionAData
        break;
      case "SECTIONB":
        return sectionBData
        break;
    }
  })()
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(importDataSuccess(section, dataSet))
  }
}
```

The problem with above approach is everytime I call `this.props.dispatch(loadData("SECTIONA"))` on `componentA` and `this.props.dispatch(loadData("SECTIONB"))` on `componentB` I get `sectionBData` on both state tree `sectionA` and `sectionB`. Even when `sectionA` is first dispatched, the `sectionB` already populated with `sectionA` data even though it has not been dispatched.

What is  the proper way to reuse the reducer and action for such case? Or do I have to create action and reducer for each section even though they are the same?

======= UPDATE =====

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  data: []
};
const sectionReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.IMPORT_DATA:
      if ( action.section ) {
        return state.data.push({ section: action.section, data: action.data });
      }
    break;
  }
  return state;
}
...
const reducers = combineReducers({
  sections: sectionReducer
});
export default reducers;
```

Action

```
export const importData= (section, data) => {
  return {
    type: types.IMPORT_DATA,
    section,
    data
  }
}
export const loadData = (section) => {
  const dataSet = (() => {
    switch(section) {
      case "SECTIONA":
        return sectionAData
        break;
      case "SECTIONB":
        return sectionBData
        break;
    }
  })()
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(importData(section, dataSet))
  }
}
```

The component

```
class SectionWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadData(this.props.const))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Section
          title={this.props.title}
          id={this.props.id}
          data={this.props.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = function(store, ownProps) {
  const section = store.sections.find( (item) => { return item.section === ownProps.const; })
  const data = section.data
  return {
    data
  };
}
SectionWrapper.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  const: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SectionWrapper);
```

Store

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware  = compose(
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    createLogger()
  ),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  createStoreWithMiddleware
);

export default store;
```

Comment: That's because `sectionA` and `sectionB` is referencing the same reducer `sectionReducer` and therefore will have the same data.

Comment: Yea I understand that. But is there any other way to reuse the reducer and action without creating another one?

Comment: You're dispatching the same action, and this action is present in both reducers. You need to make two different action types, returned by one or two action creators (better two different than one universal).

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin when you say two different action types, is it like `IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS_A` and `IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS_B` but still uses the same reducer and action?

Comment: Two actions are different when they have different types, so in this case everything is clean. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, when `sectionReducer` receives an action of type `IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS`, It replaces the entire state with the data received... so there could be only one section and data in the state., Which is obviously what you don't want.

What you can do is, In your `sectionReducer`

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

const sectionReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case types.IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS:
      // action contains { type, section, data }
      // added if statement to make sure data is not empty.
      if ( action.section && action.data ) {
        state.data.push({ section: action.section, data: action.data });
        return Object.assign( {}, state );
      }
      return state;

    case types.UPDATE_IMPORTED_DATA:
      // action contains { section, data }
      let index = state.data.findIndex( item => { return item.section === action.section; });
      state.data[index] = { section: action.section, data: action.data }
      return state;

    default:
     return state;

  }

}
```

Using this method you can store `n` number of sections and also update them very easily.

And when you want to access the data of specific section, you can do

```
let findSectionByName = ( sections, section_name ) => {
  return sections.find( (item) => { return item.section === section_name; })
}
let section = findSectionByName( state.sections, 'SECTIONA' );
```

You will also have to change

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  sectionA: sectionReducer,
  sectionB: sectionReducer
});
```

to

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  sections: sectionReducer,
});
```

Comment: Now when I do `loadData(section_name)`, I can see from redux-logger the prev state `sections.data` has one item with my data, but then changed to `sections: 1` in next state. I have no idea how it is changed to `1`

Comment: Updated the code, added `if statement` at `case types.IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS:`, Also you should change `loadData` function and `debug` the component/application to check why its called 5 times instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the update. A bit inspection everytime doing push it changes the state `sections` value to the number of items inside the array rather than the array itself. So if I call the action twice it will be `sections: 2`. I try to change the push into `state.data[action.section]` it results the state as `sections[0] => {data:[..], section:'..'}`, the `data` gone from `sections`. But idk how the `action.section` key changed into index so that the second time action is called it replaces the index 0. `state[state.length]` still gives index 0

Comment: Ok, in `case types.IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS:` can you do `console.log(action)` and let me know how the entire log/data structure looks like? you can also paste the console.log somewhere and link the url here.

Comment: Here is screenshoot from the console http://prnt.sc/chfmo4. I change `IMPORT_DATA_SUCCESS` into `IMPORT_DATA`. That one uses your code above. I put the `console.log` right before the if block

Comment: This means somewhere we/you're setting the `sections` value to `1`, i..e we're actually `mutating` the data outside.., Is there any possibility you could upload the code on github.. or atleast share the entire code of reducer, actions and the component consuming it.

Comment: Sorry the project is on private repo. But I've added the component and store. The reducer only has `IMPORT_DATA` and the action has `importData` and `loadData` same as above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123242/discussion-between-random-user-and-spondbob).

Comment: After `if ( action.section ) {` statement in your `sectionReducer` add `return state;`